# React with Typescript: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'History'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, routes

I'm trying to navigate away from a view by pushing into the history object. However when I try to push a route into it, I get an error message:

*Property 'push' does not exist on type 'History'.*

```
render(){
  return (
    <div className="loginWrapper">
      withRouter(({history}) => (<button onClick={()=>{history.push('/home')}} className="btn btn-primary">Pieteikties</button>))
    </div>
  )  
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

I also tried this:

```
logIn(){
  this.props.history.push('/new-location')
}
```

with a component like this:

```
render(){
  return (
    <div className="loginWrapper">
      <button onClick={this.logIn} className="btn btn-primary">Pieteikties</button>
    </div>
  )  
}
```

And it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where did you define `history` here? There is a global [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) which is a web standard. If you want to use the [react-router history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history), it's passed as a prop. Try `props.history.push()` instead.

The component must receive the `history` prop from react router. So it should be a direct child of a `Route` component, for example, or you must pass down props via its parents.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. What's that `logIn()` function? Where does it get it's `this.props` from? Try using `this.props.history.push` in the __render__ method.

Comment: logIn() function is a method that this component has. I tried using this.props.history.push in the render method and it fails, because this.props.history is undefined.

Comment: The component must receive the `history` prop from react router. So it should be a direct child of a `Route` component, for example, or you must pass down props via it's parents. This is something that is explained in the documentation for react router. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props

Answer (score 23):

UPDATE:
I found a new way to do this type of thing.
Same as b4 you need to install them types:

1.- `npm i react-router react-router-dom`

2.- `npm i -D @types/react-router @types/react-router-dom`

```js
import React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

interface MyComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps {
 someOfYourOwnProps: any;
 someMorePropsIfNeedIt: any;
}

interface MyComponentState {
  someProperty: any;
  another: any;
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {

    public state: MyComponentState;
    public constructor (props: MyComponentProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            someProperty: "",
            another: ""
        }
    }

    public onClickHandler (evt: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>): void {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

    public componentDidMount () {
        this.props.history;
    }
   public render (): React.ReactElement<MyComponentProps> {
        return (
            <div>trol</div>
        )
    }
}
```

---

hihitl i know whats happening. Hope you sill need it.

1.- `npm i react-router react-router-dom`

2.- `npm i -D @types/react-router @types/react-router-dom`

```js
import React from "react";
import { History, LocationState } from "history";

interface MyComponentProps {
 someOfYourOwnProps: any;
 history: History<LocationState>;
 someMorePropsIfNeedIt: any;
}
```

then  on your component if it is a class do

```js
class MyComponent extends Component<MyComponentProps, {}> {}
```

if it is a functional

```js
const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {}
```

Comment: this is the only working solution for me in create-react-app + typescript kind of setup when I want to push history in a component.

Comment: For my cra typescript app the import { History, LocationState } from "history"; and history: History<LocationState>; was exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: interface MYINTERFACE extends RouteComponentProps {}
worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In React 16 and above you can use Redirect from 'react-router-dom'. In your case you will get same outcomes if you use redirect instead history.

```
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Define state in your component

```
this.state = {
  loginStatus:true
}
```

than in your render method

```
render () {
if(this.state.loginStatus){
    return <Redirect to='/home'  />
 }
return(
 <div> Please Login </div>
 )
}
```

**Edit: using this.props.history**

There are two things I found missing in your code. One is your login method 
   binding. Bind your method so that you can get access to `this` of class. 
   Other things is use `withRouter` HOC. `withRouter` will give you 
   access to the this.history prop. Like so below.

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class MainClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      this.login = this.login.bind(this)
   }

  logIn(){
      this.props.history.push('/new-location')
   }

   render(){
     return (
       <div className="loginWrapper">
          <button onClick={this.logIn} className="btn btn- 
          primary">Pieteikties</button>
      </div>
      )  
    }

 export default withRouter(MainClass);
```

Comment: Redirect has some caveats though such as not being able to use the browser back button.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can try this. Let me know if you get the error now.