# What are the basic tools and techniques for debugging third-party types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get better at TypeScript. I feel pretty solid on the programming concepts, but I'm struggling with understanding the workflow of including things like DefinitelyTyped.

Here's an **example**. Please note **I'm not asking about these specific details** but rather how to approach the TypeScript development workflow in general.

### The Example

I'm programming happily in my web app. I want to use the history hook `useHistory()` from react router and push a location. So I put it in my functional component and then want to pass the `history` object to a helper function.

```
const helperFn = (history) => history.push('/location');

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  helperFn(helperFn);
  // ...
}
```

So I get the obvious error from `doSomething` that the `history` argument implicitly has the `any` type. I look at the hinting in my IDE which suggests that `useHistory()` returns the `History` type, so I do this:

```
const helperFn = (history: History) => history.push('/location');
```

But that doesn't work: `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'History'`. Fine, I've learned to check that I have all the `@types/*` modules installed, so I double check I've got `@types/react-router` and `@types/react-router-dom`. No dice. I try to read the `index.d.ts` file in those modules to see if I can divine what's going on, but as a non-expert it's hard to read and I don't see the problem. Then I go to my fallback strategy of googling the error message. I find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152417/react-with-typescript-property-push-does-not-exist-on-type-history) from which I learn that the correct import line is:

```
import { History, LocationState } from "history";
```

And the correct type is in fact:

```
History<LocationState>
```

At which point I throw up my hands. How the heck was I supposed to know that these types were to be imported from the "history" module (which I never installed!!), and that it was this generic `History` rather than whatever other `History` type was being used before?

### The Question

**What are the basic tools and techniques for debugging third-party types in TypeScript?**

Here are some more specific questions to clarify:

1. When a third-party type, especially those from DefinitelyTyped, isn't correct for your code, how do you examine them? How do you find out what properties they have so you can check if it's your code that's using the type wrong or if it's the wrong type for your code? How do you tell what file it's defined in?
2. When you're using code that isn't typed, how do you go about finding the right type? Sometimes just installing the corresponding module from DefinitelyTyped magically fixes it, but when it doesn't, I don't feel like I have any tools to diagnose the problem.

Btw I use Sublime Text and I have the TypeScript package installed and the code hints are reasonably useful, but they don't answer these questions for me.

Comment: I sometimes run into incorrect types. Maybe something is missing or something is wrong when running my code. When that happens I dig into the actual source, look at the DefinitelyTyped definition, fix it and send a PR.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how else to answer this. DefinitelyTyped definitions are hand-written by humans and so can you. Do you have trouble analyzing the `.d.ts` files? It's hard to know exactly what wall you are hitting.

Comment: In the case of your `History` example, I think I would have just used 'go to definition' to try and find out what this History type really was...

Comment: @Evert looks like "go to definition" is thing I'm missing. If I go through the things the TypeScript package for Sublime Text supports, I find it bound to F12. Thanks!

Comment: @Evert if you want some easy karma, paste that comment re: "go to definition" in an answer. I'll upvote and accept.