# How to override non-generic types such as @types/History for useHitory()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

My goal is to override 'History' type, so I can use pass `eventKey` props for `(eventKey) => history.push(eventKey)`, I could not override `History` type from `useHistory()`, it said "Type History is not generic". The current solution I did is `const history: any = useHistory()` but I believe it defeat the purpose of types.

```
import { RouteConfigProps } from "app/routes/config";
import { RenderRoutes } from "app/routes/RenderRoutes";
import React from "react";
import { Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Home: React.FC<{routes: RouteConfigProps[]}> = ({ routes }) => {
  console.log("Home routes: ", routes)
  const history: History<> = useHistory();
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand>Hi!</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto" onSelect={(eventKey) => history.push(eventKey)>
            <Nav.Link eventKey="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link eventKey="/about">About</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link eventKey="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link eventKey="/motivational-letter">Motivational Letter</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link eventKey="/it-core-values">IT Core Values</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
      <RenderRoutes routes={routes} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Hey I think it's helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152417/react-with-typescript-property-push-does-not-exist-on-type-history

Comment: I don't understand the question, but the `useHistory` hook is a generic: `useHistory<HistoryLocationState = any>()`.  If you call `const history = useHistory<MyHistoryType>();` then the variable `history` will have the type `History<MyHistoryType>`.  But the argument which you pass to `history.push()` is not generic.  It still has the be of type `To` ([defined here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#to))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in my comment, the `useHistory()` hook *is* generic.  I think you're getting the error because there are multiple declarations for the interface `History` in multiple places, some generic and some not.  It's assuming you mean the built-in browser `History` object instead of the router history.  So it's better to apply the generic to the hook call than the returned object.

do this

```
const history = useHistory<MyHistoryType>(); // history has type History<MyHistoryType>
```

instead of this

```
const history: History<MyHistoryType> = useHistory(); // gives error History is not generic
```

But the typescript problem is what you are passing to `history.push()`.  The passed argument must be a of type [`To`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#to) which is either a `string` or a specific object `PartialPath` and does not depend on the generic of `History`.

The param which you pass as `onSelect` to the `Nav` component needs to be of type `SelectCallback` which is defined as:

```
type SelectCallback = (eventKey: string | null, e: React.SyntheticEvent<unknown>) => void
```

Do you see the mismatch yet?  `eventKey` can be either `string` or `null`, but `history.push()` can only accept to accept a `string` and not `null`.  So you need to make this conditional to filter out `null` before calling `history.push(eventKey)`.

```
const onSelect = (eventKey: string | null) => {
    if (eventKey !== null) { 
        history.push(eventKey); 
    }
}
```

That will solve your typescript errors.

Comment: Filter! That's the key to solve my problem. Do you know how to override `.push()` types?

Comment: @kidfrom what is it that you’re trying to achieve?  There are ways to suppress the typescript errors, but you’ll probably end up with runtime errors if you do that. If you push something to the router history that it can’t understand, it’s going to choke up.